# Cascading entities in( 1 to many ) in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am a totally begineer and  I have a small problem regarding cascading 1 to many rel in EF ... 
Lets say I have 3 entities a Country which has many Cityes , each city has many hotels ...

```
class Country 
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string CountryName {get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cityes {get; set; }  
}

class City 
{
   public int Id {get; set; }
   public string CityName {get; set; }
   public virtual Country Country {get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Hotel> Hotels {get; set; }
}

class Hotel 
{
   public int Id {get; set; }
   public string HotelName {get; set; }
   public virtual City City {get; set; }
}
```

And here is my simple Repository

```
public IQueryable<Hotel> GetAllHotels()
{
   return context.HotelTable.Include("City");
}
```

And in my MVC client I have a simple projection

```
public class HotelVm 
{
   public string HotelName  {get; set; }
   public string CityName {get; set; }
   public string CountryName {get; set; } // here is the problem
}
```

And a Factory Model for the projection

```
public class Factory 
{
    public HotelVm Create(Hotel h)
    {
       return new HotelVm()
       {
          HotelName = h.HotelName , 
          CityName = h.City.CityName , 
          CountryName = ??? 
       }
    }
 }
```

And finally the Controller in my MVC

```
public Repository repo = new Repository();
public Factory fact = new Factory ();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    IQueryable<Hotel> hotel = repo.GetAllHotels();
    var result = hotel.ToList().Select(h=> fact.Create(h));
    return View(result);
}
```

Now clearly I get on my Create `HotelVM` an Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ... In my Create new `HotelVm` ... 
Not sure exactly  how to get the name of the Country in my projection or if I should bring a different strategy ... 
Any help would be great.

Comment: Add `.Include("Country")` to your repository to include the country data into the City and do basic defensive programming in your factory.

Comment: @Romoku  adding an Include("Country")  means I have to add on my Hotel entity a nav property Country Country ... Wont I get something like a self referencing loop ?

Comment: Sorry I meant `.Include("City.Country")`. It is possible to [load related entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

Comment: Thanks didnt know about that ... Really helpful , how do I vote your answer  or like or something ? And how do I close the topic since its solved ?

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer.

Comment: I have posted my answer. You can mark answers as accepted that answer your question. Once you have accepted an answer the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the repository to load related entities for the `City`.

```
public IQueryable<Hotel> GetAllHotels()
{
   return context.HotelTable.Include("City").Include("City.Country");
}
```

Then modify the factory to use the `Country` belonging to the `City`.

```
public class Factory 
{
    public HotelVm Create(Hotel h)
    {
        return new HotelVm()
        {
            HotelName = h.HotelName, 
            CityName = h.City.CityName, 
            CountryName = h.City.Country.CountryName
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to use defensive coding practices to prevent exceptions such as the `NullReferenceException`.

See also: [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)